# Why can't I upgrade my AWS EC2 m5.xlarge Instance to m5.4xlarge instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance of type `m5.xlarge` and I want to upgrade it to `m5.4xlarge`. But when I chose to change type the only option I am presented with is the `m5.xlarge` type, which is the type my instance is already in. See the screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check in different regions. Maybe in your current region there are no such instances.

Comment: I have done that. `m5.4xlarge` appears in the list of types when I create an instance from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

is your instance still running?
Solution 1, You can stop your instance first and upgrade your instance.
Solution 2, create a new AMI from your current instance, then create a new instance from that AMI and select `m5.4xlarge`

Comment: It's not running. It is stopped. Otherwise, one is not allowed to click on the Change Instance Type option.